# execute other class before executing the main windows form application class

Tags: vb.net

I've been given a windows form application written in VB. For some reasons I will need to execute the second class before the form application in the first class. The form class has to be the first class in the file. I can't simply inherit the second class and call the functions, because it has already used up the only allowable inheritance. I did some research and found there is something called main procedure that determines which codes executes first? It is automatically generated for any windows form application, but I simply can't find that file. Any thoughts on that? or any other ways that I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Follow [Start VB.NET GUI app using Sub Main or form startup object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311346/start-vb-net-gui-app-using-sub-main-or-form-startup-object) for better alternatives.

But if you really need to start with Main(), follow these steps.

1. Open application settings.
2. Uncheck "Enable application framework"
3. Set startup object to "Sub Main"

[image]

Then add a new source file (.vb) and include Main() in it

```
    Module MainModule
        Sub Main()
            'Your code here
        End Sub
    End Module
```