# How to find the main() entry point in a VB.Net winforms app?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

When I create a WinForms app in C#, the output type is `Windows Application` and I get a `program.cs` with a `static void Main()` which I can use to handle command-line parameters, etc...

However, when I create an equivalent project for VB, the application type is `Windows Forms Application` and I'm forced to pick a startup form.

Is there an equivalent mechanism to run my own code before I decide which form to display in VB.Net? I'm assuming the same code exists but is auto-generated and hidden somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start VB.NET GUI app using Sub Main or form startup object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311346/start-vb-net-gui-app-using-sub-main-or-form-startup-object)

Comment: That discusses why it should be done or not, it doesn't say how to do it...

Comment: @Basic Did you get it to work with parameters? I use the steps mention on the answer. But when I tried to pass parameters from cmd it does not work.  I have my Main as Public Sub Main (ByVal args As String()) and then printing each element of the array in a for each ... using Console.WriteLine...I run the application from cmd but does not print the parameters that i pass. Any help please

Comment: @omachu23 It worked fine for me so you must be doing something a little wrong. I've also been stuck in C# for a long time and VB.Net syntax is a little Rusty. Shouldn't that be `ByVal args() As String` ? (Note brackets moved). Easiest way to get this solved is to use the button at the top right and ask a question, then more people will be able to focus on it

Comment: @Basic I cannot believe I missed that! I changed that and it works now! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer !! Cheers

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In VB you'll need to create your sub main by hand as it were so what I generally do is create a new Module named Program.

Within that as a very basic setup you'll need to add the following code.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
    Application.Run(New Form1)

End Sub
```

Once you've done that go to the application tab of the project's settings and uncheck the 'Enable Application framework' setting and then from the drop down under Startup object select your new Sub Main procedure.

You can then put any start-up code that you want to run before your program opens its main form before the Application.Run line.

Hope that helps

Comment: Nice solution. If you use this approach you will also need to re-implement any Application Events in your module such as Application.ApplicationExit and Application.ThreadException etc...

Comment: You could run code before any forms are loaded using the MyApplication_Startup event. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup?view=netframework-4.8 for more info. This avoids having to implement Sub Main().

Answer (score 0):

*If your application has only one form* you may simply start typing Sub New() and Visual Studio will autogenerate this method stub which executes first.  No project setting changes required.

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call
    '==> Put your pre-execution steps here.
End Sub
```

Comment: That wasn't the question, this is tied to the startup form, he was wanting code to be able to run before the startup form. The accepted answer is correct.

Comment: @MarkHall is correct. Note the difference between `Sub Main()` (the initial entry point for the application) and `Sub New()` (The constructor for - in this case -  a form). The former is executed before anything else is started (no form, message pump, etc) and allows you to handle command line arguments, choose visual styles and similar

Comment: Yes, I did not recognize the original question was dealing with multiple forms.  I edited my response above to clarify that a Sub New() only provides pre-initialization access when your app has a single form.  Thank you for your comments.