# create a message box on application start requiring users name then display it in the program?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I would like a message box to pop-up at the start of the program asking what the customers name is. I then want this name to be displayed in a label that i have already created.

I went to application events and entered the code below after finding a few helpful tips around the internet. I get a message box allowing me to enter the customers name, so that bit works fine. The problem comes when I try to change the label. It says that 'label4' is not declared. I'm guessing that the application events section is a completely different section from the other forms.

If anyone could explain how I would go about doing this correctly and also explain the difference between so I can learn from this that would be great.

```
Dim message, title, defaultValue, myvalue As String 

' Set prompt.
message = "Please Enter The Customers Name" 

' Set title.
title = "New Customer"

' Set default value.
defaultValue = ""   

' Display message, title, and default value.
myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)

label4.text = myvalue
```

Comment: sounds like you dug down too deep and are trying to set the label before it has been created.  Just do the message box in FormLoad event

Answer (score 1):

The controls of a form a defined locally to that form, i.e. they are private members of that form and cannot be accessed from outside. Now it depends how your code is organized. If you are calling the InputBox before opening the main form then you need a way to pass the customer name to the main form. You can do that in the constructor the main form.

```
' In the main form
Public Sub New(ByVal customerName As String)
    InitializeComponent() ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
    label4.Text = customerName
End Sub
```

Then you can create the main form like this (see also [How to find the main() entry point in a VB.Net winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307397/880990))

```
Public Sub Main()
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

    ...

    myValue = InputBox(message, title, defaultValue)

    Dim frm As Form1 = New Form1(myValue)
    ' Starts the application.
    Application.Run(frm)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining, makes much more sense. However, I have a slight problem with application.run(frm), it states that 'Value of type form1 cannot be converted to 1 dimensional array of string'. Any clue how to solve this or whats wrong?