# Is there a way to get the input from a Load event handler (entered via inputBox) to be used Globally in the program?

Tags: vb.net, events, handler

I am creating a form that will prompt the user to enter a file name upon loading the file. The issue I encounter is that my variable I use to store the input is not recognized in another one of my procedures. The code here shows my current set up.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmEmployee
Sub frmEmployee_load(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim strFileName = InputBox("Please name the file you would like to save the data to: ")

End Sub
Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    txtEmail.Clear()
    txtExtension.Clear()
    txtFirst.Clear()
    txtLast.Clear()
    txtMiddle.Clear()
    txtNumber.Clear()
    txtPhone.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

Dim inputFile As New StreamWriter(strFileName)

    If File.Exists(strFileName) = True Then
        inputFile = File.CreateText(strFileName)
        inputFile.Write(txtEmail.Text)
        inputFile.Write(txtExtension.Text)
        inputFile.Write(txtFirst.Text)
        inputFile.Write(txtLast.Text)
        inputFile.Write(txtMiddle.Text)
        inputFile.Write(txtNumber.Text)
        inputFile.Write(txtPhone.Text)
        inputFile.Write(cmbDepart.Text)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("" & strFileName & "Cannot be created or found.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

The load event handler is where I want the user to input the name of the file.

Comment: Read up on [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)  `strFileName` is declared locally, so it exists only in the form load method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `My.Settings` and load the file string there and save it. All forms can now access that. When you close the the app set it to `String.Empty` if you want it to be.

You also could be taking advantage of a class object for the fields you are capturing then using either `BinaryFormatter` or `XmlSerializer` to store the data. Better databinding, creation and reconstruction using an object.

```
My.Settings.Filename = Inputbox("Filename?")
My.Settings.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the scope of your variable to outside of your load method...

```
 Public Class frmEmployee

 Private strFileName As String

 Sub frmEmployee_load(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  strFileName = InputBox("Please name the file you would like to save the data to: ")
 End Sub
```

Comment: You can't declare the Private variable outside the class.

Comment: My bad posting from phone.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the approach you have there is that your variabl strFileName is scoped to the class frmEmployee.

You need to set up a genuinely global variable (at the application startup) an then use that.  So you will need a Sub Main as an entry point to your application See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306903/how-to-find-the-main-entry-point-in-a-vb-net-winforms-app/14307397#14307397), and just before that create a public variable to hole the file name.

So you might have something like this for your application startup:

```
Public fileNametoUse as string

Public Sub Main()

    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
    Application.Run(New Form1)

End Sub
```

Then in you load sub for frmEmployee you would have:

```
fileNametoUse =  InputBox("Please name the file you would like to save the data to: ")
```

Comment: I think you have an error in your code `==` that wont compile... Maybe an overlook?

Comment: Thank you , you're right a simple typo but one that does mean it wouldn't compile.  Corrected now.