# Operator '+' is not defined for types

Tags: vb.net

I'm just getting back into coding to make a simple program to help with a project. I need to get html code into a string and I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I'm just not sure what it is. Code is below...

```
Public Class Code_Generator
Dim r1 As String
Dim r2 As String
Dim r3 As String
Dim r4 As String
Dim Code As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Day.Text = r1
    Week.Text = r2
    Month.Text = r3
    Weekend.Text = r4
    Code = "<div id=""DL"">Day</div><div id=""DR"">$" + Day + "</div><br><div id=""DL"">Week</div><div id=""DR"">$" + Week + "</div><br><div id=""DL"">Month</div><div id=""DR"">$" + Month + "</div><br><div id=""DL"">Weekend</div> <div id=""DR"">$" + Weekend + "</div> <br>"
    MessageBox.Show(Code)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's `&` for strings.

Comment: Also, use either `r1` or `Day.Text`,etc. Presumably, `Day` is a control, and does not have a useful `.ToString()` method.

Comment: And just one more thing, you might like [interpolated strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings), which would let you write `code = $"<div id=""DL"">Day</div><div id=""DR"">${r1}</div><br><div id=""DL"">Week</div><div id=""DR"">${r2}</div><br><div id=""DL"">Month</div><div id=""DR"">${r3}</div><br><div id=""DL"">Weekend</div> <div id=""DR"">${r4}</div> <br>"`.

Comment: Definitely like the interpolated strings, thanks for that one. I have one more question that I'm pretty sure is even dumber but I can't remember for the life of me. How do I fix the error BC30420 'Sub Main' was not found in...

Comment: This question might help: [How to find the main() entry point in a VB.Net winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14306903/880990).

Comment: I've solved it and got it running, thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The operator (+) works for string concatenation, the same way the operator (&).

But the variables Day, Week, Month and Weekend refers to a TextBox (maybe another control), with the .Text property.

You are trying to concatenate the string "<div..." with the TextBox control itself. And there is no operator to do this.

You must concatenate the string with the .Text property of the TextBoxes:

Code = "<div..." & Day.Text & "..." & Week.Text ... and so on.

*I suggest you to use (&) for string concatenation, but it's totally a personal preference.